# Clone desktop Ubuntu on a pendrive to run on another machine

Tags: usb, usb-drive, clone

I would like to clone my desktop Ubuntu onto a pendrive so that it could be installed onto another machine with all my settings and files.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and the best option is to use a live CD like [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php).

You could also boot with any Live CD and use **dd** to clone the disk:

```
dd if=[disk_with_ubuntu] of=[pendrive] bs=512 conv=noerror,sync
```

Where `[disk_with_ubuntu]` is the disk containing your Ubuntu installation (f.e. `/dev/sda`) and `[pendrive]` is your pendrive. You have to be *very sure* about these parameters, otherwise you might overwrite the wrong disk. That's why I recommend using a live CD designed for this precise task.